# How can I have the Apply To Each ignore subfolders?

Tags: power-automate

I have a power automate flow that is supposed to move files from an sftp to a one driver folder. In that sftp folder there are (currently) 5 files and 3 sub folders. Those 3 sub folders have hundreds of files but we are not concerned with those.

What seems to be happening is that the Apply To Each is going through all of the subfolders instead of just the files in my the parent folder. How can I have it not go into the subfolders?

Comment: Show us the flow as well as the list of folders you’re talking about. Hard to help without some visuals.

Comment: Like Skin already mentioned, please share a screenshot your flow setup. Just had a quick look at the documentation of the SFTP connector. Looks like the response returned of these type actions should include an IsFolder boolean property: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/sftpwithssh/#blobmetadataresponse You should be able to use that in a condition or Filter Array action.